# Ant Design Cards. Adding more information to Meta

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import { Card } from 'antd';
const { Meta } = Card;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card
    hoverable
    style={{ width: 240 }}
    cover={<img alt="example" src="https://os.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/QBnOOoLaAfKPirc.png" />}
  >
    <Meta
      title="Europe Street beat"
      description="www.instagram.com"
    />
  </Card>
, mountNode);
```

From AntDesign's example, in the Card's Meta section, is there a way I would be able to add more description to the card like "price" or "author" and display it?

Comment: why not do something like this;  description={
                  <div>
                    <p>first content</p>
                    <p>second content</p>
                    
                    </div> }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Meta` supports only fixed properties like `title` and `description`. https://ant.design/components/card/#Card.Meta

But if you want to add extra fields to the card, you can just add them to the `Card` html as children:

```
<Card
    hoverable
    style={{ width: 240 }}
    cover={<img alt="example" src="https://os.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/QBnOOoLaAfKPirc.png" />}
  >
    <Meta
      title="Europe Street beat"
      description="www.instagram.com"
    />
    <div className="additional">
      <p className="price">Price: 20$</p>
      <p>Author: John Doe</p>
    </div>
  </Card>
```

See [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/qxJrEe?editors=0110).

Answer (score 0):

it can be done like this

```
const { Card } = antd;
const { Meta } = Card;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card
    hoverable
   style={{ width: 240 }}
   cover={<img alt="example" src="https://os.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/QBnOOoLaAfKPirc.png" />}
 >
<Meta
  title="Europe Street beat"
  description={[
         <div>
             <p>"www.instagram.com"</p>
             <p> additional content</p>
          </div>
        ]}
      />
   <div className="additional">
     <p className="price">Price: <span className="quantity">20$</span></p>
     <p>Author: <span className="quantity">John Doe</span></p>
   </div>
   </Card>
  , mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Meta`** supports only fixed properties like **title** and **description**. But If you want to add more details to your Card you can do it with help of **`description`** prop which supports by **`Meta`**.

You just need to write code as you do in JSX.

```
<Card hoverable style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 16 }}>
        <Meta
          description={                   //Add your specific data here in description
            <>
              <div className="subject-card_extra-content">
               <img src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" style={{width:20}}/>
               <span>Data</span>
              </div>

              <div className="dashboard-subject_inline-actions">
                <Icon type="video-camera" />
                <p>
                  Total Videos :<span> {5} </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <Button htmlType="submit" icon="play-circle" className="custom-default-fill-btn">
                Continue Learning
              </Button>

              <Button htmlType="submit" icon="play-circle" className="custom-default-fill-btn">
                No Progress
              </Button>
            </>
          }
        />
      
    </Card>
```